# How could Edna afford to feed all those people?

Tags: plot-explanation, places-in-the-heart

In *Places in the Heart* (1984) Edna could barely keep food on the table for herself, her two kids, her boarder and her handyman. So how did she feed those new workers? She couldn't even pay her monthly mortgage! And, by the way, how did or could she have paid her monthly utilities?